# Morsecode using static

Tags: java, morse-code

I have this program but i have a few problems:
This is the place where i do the calcs.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MorseCode {
 public MorseCode()
    {
    }//end default constructor
    public String[] translateHere(String s)throws IOException
    {
        String compare = s, codedLine = "";  //userInput toUpperCase
        int length = compare.length();  //length of userInput
        String line, file = "C:\\APCS  Course B\\Unit 4\\Unit 4 Documents\\morse.txt";// variable holding file name and variable for each letter/number
        char code;
        //Constants
        final int MAX = 36;
        //Arrays
        char[] morseLetter = new char[MAX];
        String[] morseCode = new String[MAX];
        String[] newMessage = new String[length];
        //putting user input in a character array;
        char[] userLetters = compare.toCharArray();
        //object creation
        File openFile = new File(file);
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(openFile);
        int  counter = 0;
        while(inFile.hasNext())
            {
                line = inFile.next();
                code = (char)line.charAt(0);
                //System.out.println(code);
                morseLetter[counter] = code;
                morseCode[counter] = inFile.next();
                counter++;
            }//end nested while loop
        for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < MAX; k++)
            {
                if(userLetters[j] == morseLetter[k])
                {
                    newMessage[j] = morseCode[k];
                }
            }//end nested for loop
        }//end for loop
        return newMessage;
    }//end method that completes translateion
    public String toString(String a, String[] b)
{
   System.out.println("Input: " + a);
   System.out.println("Output:");
   String output = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
   {
      output = output + b[i];
   }
   return output;
 }//end toString method
}//end Translate Class
```

The main methods:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MorseCodeTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        String userInput;
        final String SENTINEL = "0";//for exiting program when entered
        //object creation
        MorseCode text = new MorseCode();
        //getting user input to be translated
        do
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter what you wish to translte to Morse code (no punctuation): ");
            userInput = in.nextLine();
            String compare = userInput.toUpperCase();
            String[] codedText = new String[compare.length()];
            codedText = text.translateHere(compare);
            text.toString(userInput, codedText);
        }while(!userInput.equals(SENTINEL));
    }//end main
}//end class
```

So my program is when I put in a input the output shows black even tho in the main methods i did the calculation that would convert it to Morse Code. Also is there any suggestions on if i could use the static identifier in any of my methods.

Here is the text file:

```
1 .----

2 ..---

3 ...--

4 ....-

5 .....

6 -....

7 --...

8 ---..

9 ----.

0 -----

A .-

B -...

C -.-.

D -..

E .

F ..-.

G --.

H ....

I ..

J .---

K -.-

L .-..

M --

N -.

O ---

P .--.

Q --.-

R .-.

S ...

T -

U ..-

V ...-

W .--

X -..-

Y -.--

Z --..
```

Comment: Use a debugger, and step through the code line by line.

Comment: I tried it still not working.

Comment: if(userLetters[j] == morseLetter[k]){newMessage[j] = morseCode[k];} - do you print out in here to see that the translation is actually happening at all?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. Are you asking me if the translation is happening at all as in without the other methods with it.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to have a System.out.print(<morseCode[k] maybe?>) in there and then run the code as you intend it work - and see if the desired morse code symbols are being found. Just a debugging suggestion. ... . .  _.__ ._

Comment: Yes it is working except the code is showing like this ....---.--.-.-..-.-----..-Input: how are you
Output:           But i want it so that it shows it after the Output:

Comment: Nvm i just edited it thank you for the help. It is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should use a hashmap to key the morse code by letter, this makes your code much simpler.
Getting the morsecode for a letter is then a simple lookup.

Also you could just load the data once, maybe in the Constructor of MorseCode.

But to get at your question, you are just not printing the output. Just returning it and not showing it on the console.

if you change your toString method to look like this, it should print out something.

```
public String toString(String a, String[] b) {
    System.out.println("Input: " + a);
    System.out.print("Output:"); // changed to a print, to avoid newline
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        output = output + b[i];
    }
    System.out.println(output); // this was missing
    return output;
}//end toString method
```